# Python Oauthlibary & Tweepy Error: Only unicode objects are escapable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, tweepy

I'm new to python and I'm trying to build a bot that connects to my twitter account. I have some basic code to access my account with my twitter developer credentials but when I try to test it using:

```
    API = create_api()
    API.update_status('Hello World!')'
```

I get a ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type  from the oauth libary. Which triggers a tweepy error of the same type : tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type .

How do I resolve this error?

I've tried from **future** import unicode_literals but I still get the same error.

```
    CONSUMER_KEY = consumer_keys
    CONSUMER_SECRET = consumer_secrets
    ACCESS_TOKEN = access_tokens
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = access_token_secrets

    logger = logging.getLogger()


    def create_api():
        consumer_key = os.getenv(CONSUMER_KEY)
        consumer_secret = os.getenv(CONSUMER_SECRET)
        access_token = os.getenv(ACCESS_TOKEN)
        access_token_secret = os.getenv(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

        api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
       # api object is being used to talk to twitter
        try:
            api.verify_credentials()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
            raise e
        logger.info("API created")
        return api


     API = create_api()
     API.update_status('Hello World!')
```

Error List:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\pythonw.exe 
C:\PycharmProjects/TwitterBot/config.py
Error creating API
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
proxies=self.api.proxy)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 88, in __call__
unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 313, in sign
('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 127, in get_oauth_signature
uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 210, in _render
request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 32, in wrapper
return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\parameters.py", line 59, in prepare_headers
escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 57, in escape
'Got %r of type %s.' % (u, type(u)))
ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PycharmProjects/TwitterBot/config.py", line 28, in create_api
api.verify_credentials()
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 605, in verify_credentials
)(**kargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
return method.execute()
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 191, in execute
six.reraise(TweepError, TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
proxies=self.api.proxy)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 88, in __call__
unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 313, in sign
('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 127, in get_oauth_signature
uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 210, in _render
request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site- packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 32, in wrapper
return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\parameters.py", line 59, in prepare_headers
escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 57, in escape
'Got %r of type %s.' % (u, type(u)))
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
proxies=self.api.proxy)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 88, in __call__
unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 313, in sign
('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 127, in get_oauth_signature
uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 210, in _render
request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 32, in wrapper
return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\parameters.py", line 59, in prepare_headers
escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 57, in escape
'Got %r of type %s.' % (u, type(u)))
ValueError: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PycharmProjects/TwitterBot/config.py", line 36, in <module>
API = create_api()
File "C:/PycharmProjects/TwitterBot/config.py", line 31, in create_api
raise e
File "C:/PycharmProjects/TwitterBot/config.py", line 28, in create_api
api.verify_credentials()
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 605, in verify_credentials
)(**kargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
return method.execute()
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 191, in execute
six.reraise(TweepError, TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 189, in execute
proxies=self.api.proxy)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\requests_oauthlib\oauth1_auth.py", line 88, in __call__
unicode(r.url), unicode(r.method), None, r.headers)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 313, in sign
('oauth_signature', self.get_oauth_signature(request)))
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 127, in get_oauth_signature
uri, headers, body = self._render(request)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\__init__.py", line 210, in _render
request.oauth_params, request.headers, realm=realm)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 32, in wrapper
return target(params, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\parameters.py", line 59, in prepare_headers
escaped_value = utils.escape(value)
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\TwitterBot\lib\site-packages\oauthlib\oauth1\rfc5849\utils.py", line 57, in escape
'Got %r of type %s.' % (u, type(u)))
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You may be misinterpreting the error. My hunch is that your keys/secrets/tokens aren't set as Env Vars and defaulting to None. The auth code is complaining that at least one of them is not set. Add some print statements to verify the inputs to tweepy are correct.

Comment: @osowskit Thank you for your comment. It is likely as you said that the env variables were not being set because when I removed os, future, and logging I was able to get it to work.